# GetKeyUp is working inconsistently in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my first Unity project, so I am making a Subway Surfers ripoff to practice it. I had created the jump and move right functionality which was working correctly, but when pressing on 'd'(To move right), it was taking the input multiple times and trying to move right multiple times, so I changed the input event from GetKey to GetKeyUp, so that the event is triggered once the player leaves the key since that happens for only one frame during a click. This caused the code to work inconsistently and making movements only once before refusing to take any more inputs.

Here is my code:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
     if (Input.GetKeyUp("w") && rb.position.y-startp.y<=0)//To jump
     {
         Vector3 gravity = Physics.gravity;
         double velocity = Math.Sqrt(-2 * gravity.y * 1.2);
         rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, (float)velocity,0);
     }
 
 
     if (Input.GetKeyUp("d"))//To move right
     {
         Debug.Log("D is pressed");
         if (rb.position.x != startp.x+1)
         {
             rb.position = new Vector3(rb.position.x+1,rb.position.y,rb.position.z);
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.Log("Head hit");
         }
     }
}
```

What should I do to make it work again? The functionalities worked fine with GetKey, but allowed multiple inputs, but with GetKeyUp it is not working consistently.

Comment: Do no use `Input` in `FixedUpdate`.  Use `Update` instead.  The `rigidbody` stuff needs to be in `FixedUpdate`.  From unity docs: `Note: Input flags are not reset until Update. You should make all the Input calls in the Update Loop.`

Comment: So I call the event in Update, but the execution in FixedUpdate? Do I do that with an intermediate boolean which flips True when the event is called, then the FixedUpdate checks if the boolean is true, executes the commands and sets boolean to false after?

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah was about to respond saying that is a good way to handle that.  Cheers.